# Switch old light switch to new dimmer

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light, old-house

I've moved into a older US home

I'm trying to update a light switch to a dimmer.

The wires are clothed but in good condition.

There are two wires going to the top side screw and one on the bottom.

I have a leviton dimmer with 4 wires, it says to use 3 overall and a 4th if necessary.

I don't see any pigtails either. I've wired newer wiring but not this.

Any advice would be appreciated. I do have a multi meter as well but was wondering if this wire configuration is even able to take the dimmer.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Trimatron-600-Watt-Single-Pole-3-Way-Universal-Push-On-Off-Rotary-Dimmer-White-Light-Almond-R00-RDL06-0TW/301370408

I've looked and can't find any answers within here.

[image]

Comment: Please post a photo of the existing wiring and the dimmer terminals and some details on the dimmer.

Comment: The two wires should have a pigtail to one screw.  Possible it is a very good(cost more) switch that has two wires per screw, but is rare.  Common is one screw, one wire.  Most switches are one wire in/one wire out plus maybe ground, so posting switch instructions will help.

Comment: I'll look for the exact model of the dimmer but it is a simple dummy dimmer

Comment: Is it one, or 2 neutrals going out of the top? And what color are the wires?

Comment: Are the wires that are bouund together and seperate white wires (neutral wires)?

Comment: The two wires adds a problem.  If to two lights, the dimmer is good.  If to a light an receptacle, then dimmer is bad.  If the two wires are power in/and out, then dimmer is good again.

Comment: All 3 are clothed and seem to be white but the bottom wire does have some black lines threaded in so I'm guessing that might be ground. I need to dig out my multimeter from the garage in one of the boxes somewhere!  As for the light, it's connected to a 4 bulb chandelier, but looks like just one wire leading up to the ceiling through chains